# How to use bull-queue with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have some links. I want to concurrently visit 3 links and scrape data. so 3 chromium tabs will be open at a time.

now my question is where I use scraperQueue.process worker.

```
  async naviageAndScrape() {
    this.log("naviagating single profile...");
    for (let link of this.links) {
      try {
        scraperQueue.add({ link });
        await this.scrapeActualData(link);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
```

actual scraping is happening here.

```
   await this.navigate(link);
   await this.log("extracting public profile...");
   const profiledetails = await this.page.evaluate(this.getDetails);
   profileStore.union("profile", profiledetails);
 }
```

Comment: Hey Ashik, could you elaborate more on what is it that you're having problems with? Any particuar error? Without details it just looks like a homework and it's really tough to offer any help.